# Querying Json with filters using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In C# I'm using Json.net to try and retrieve the sum total of 'buttonPress' where 'minutesStreamed' is over 60.

```
string json = @"
{
    'results': [
    {
        'buttonPress': 8,
        'minutesStreamed': 83
    },
    {
        'buttonPress': 3,
        'minutesStreamed': 4
    },
    {
        'buttonPress': 7,
        'minutesStreamed': 61
    }
        ]
    }";
```

I did this (below) which retrieves the Sum of the entire column, but I can't find a way to filter out anything where minutesStreamed > 60.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var buttonPresses=
    from p in obj["results"]
    select (int)p["buttonPress"];

int sum = buttonPresses.Sum();
```

The desired output would be 15 if it works correctly.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just add `where ((int)p["minutesStreamed"]) > 60` between your from and select lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `Json.NET`, you can do this with [`Linq-to-JSON`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) like this

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\results.json");
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var sum = jObj["results"]
            .Where(r => (int)r["minutesStreamed"] > 60)
            .Select(r => (int)r["buttonPress"])
            .Sum();
```

Also, notice that your `JSON` is not well-formatted, you need to separate properties of an object by comma `,` like this

```
{
    'buttonPress': 8, <= this
    'minutesStreamed': 83
}
```

Comment: You can also use [Jsonpath][1] with JToken.SelectTokens().  Also, FYI, you should always use JToken instead of JObject, in the event that the Json you pass in is in the form of an array.  JToken is the parent class of both JArray and JObject.


  [1]: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/